# Robot Framework: How to know that variable is list, dictionary or regular

Tags: python, robotframework

I need to process several types of data from one Keyword - which will call another necessary Keyword according to the defined data type.

Using `Evaluate type()` is good for Lists and Dictionaries but fails when we have just a string without quotes. If I add quotes - the data will be defined as string all times - even if it is in a List or Dictionary.

For example

```
${list}=    Create List    1    two
${type_list}=    Evaluate    type(${list})
# returns <type 'list'>

${dict}=    Create Dictionary  first=1  second=two
${type_dict}=  Evaluate  type(${dict})
# returns <type 'dict'>

${string}=  Set Variable  withoutQuotes
${type_string}=  Evaluate  type(${string})
# FAILS with:
Evaluating expression 'type(withoutQuotes)' failed: NameError: name 'withoutQuotes' is not defined
```

Could you please recommend some way to define a type of a variable which won't fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run Keyword And Return Status has helped me!

```
${passed}=    Run Keyword And Return Status   Evaluate    type(${value})
${type}=      Run Keyword If     ${passed}    Evaluate    type(${value})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new versions of Robot Framework you can call the object passing the variable without the braces, like this:

```
Test Type
    ${list}=    Create List
    ${type_list}    Evaluate    type($list)
    log    ${type_list}    warn
    # returns: <class 'list'>

    ${string}=  Set Variable  withoutQuotes
    ${type_string}=  Evaluate  type($string)
    log    ${type_string}    warn
    # returns: <class 'str'>
```